# OAuth 2.0 using 'Custom' External Identity Provider

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, claims-based-identity

I have `OWIN hosted ASP .NET Web API`. Currently it uses `Google` to provide the identity of customers. I had followed [this MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services) to implement it.

Now i am required to use company's `Cloud Service` which provides identity. Procedure with respect to user remains the same but he has to give his credentials of cloud service.

Since I can't use any inbuilt functions like `app.UseGoogleAuthentication()` as given in the docs, what should i opt to implement this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to provide more info regarding the Cloud Service. Should it be called from your app or will it be call before reaching your app. And what info does it share with your app

Comment: @MarcusH, It will be called from my Application. Say '/Login' redirects to the Cloud Service Login page. It shares username, userid, claims (all common auth details)

Comment: Ok, When the cloud service is redirecting the successful login back to your page, how does it share the user information?

Comment: @MarcusH, using 'Access Token'. Cloud Service works exactly this way - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services/_static/image3.png